# What did StackExchange use to build to popup like dialog when you click StackExchange in the Top Left?

Tags: jquery

On stackoverflow, when you click "StackExchange" in the top left, it opens a popup like dialog. Anyone know what they used to create that or what type of jQuery plugin makes such a UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't require a plugin per se. You can just `fade` a `div` containing the content with a scrollbar when you click the link. Check out Firebug, it's great for determining how things are built.

For this link particularly, it looks like most of the work is the CSS.

Comment: ya idk,,, that's what I first thought but they have some jQuery magic going on to detect the click and then load the content which I think is crazy powerful. Reminds me of Facebook, how clicking messages, requests, notifications, etc opens the dialog and then loads the content.